# Update multiple columns by ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables called `tblPurchase` and `tblInvoice`. When I Insert new record I want to update my  `TotalStock` form `tblInvoice`. I tried following code.

```
Create procedure [dbo].[spUpdateTotalStock] @Stock int, @PurchaseId int 
As
Begin
    Begin Transaction
        Update tblPurchase 
        Set TotalStock = @Stock 
        Where PurchaseId = @PurchaseId 

        RollBack Transaction
    end
```

It worked as expected. But I want to update `TotalStock` column by many ids. It means when I insert more than one invoice at the same time, I want to update my `TotalStock` column. like this

**tblInvoice**

```
ItemName | Quantity 
---------+----------
Phone       3
Mouse       6
```

**tblPurchase**

```
ItemName   | TotalStock
-----------+------------
phone           3
Mouse           6
```

`ID` comes with parameter. Always more than 10 ids come with parameter.

Comment: I'm struggling to see what this has to do with c# or MySQL

Comment: Your question has nothing to fo eith c# or asp.net. Based onthe syntax, you are using ms sql server, not mysql. Pls pay attention to the tagging of the question because you may get answers that are not in line with your expectations!

Comment: that means you want call stored procedure like this : exec spUpdateTotalStock 1,'15,18,20' ??

Answer (score 1):

> When I Insert new record I want to update my TotalStock form tblInvoice

This would normally be handled via a *trigger* not a stored procedure.  That would look something like this:

```
create trigger trig_invoice_update on tblInvoice
    after insert, update, delete
begin
    update p
         set quantity = p.quantity + coalesce(i.quantity, 0) - coalesce(d.quantity, 0)
        from tblPurchase p left join
             (select i.itemName, sum(i.quantity) as quantity
              from inserted i
              group by i.itemName
             ) i
             on p.itemName = i.itemName left join
             (select d.itemName, sum(d.quantity) as quantity
              from deleted d
              group by d.itemName
             ) d
             on p.itemName = d.itemName 
        where d.quantity <> 0 or i.quantity <> 0;
end;
```

This version handles inserts, updates, and deletes, but assumes that all items are already in the purchases table.

Comment: Thanks. its work. but it output is worng. when we minus tblPurchase Quantity from tblInvoice Quantity. its shows rows value.